# strtol() outputs wrong number

Tags: c

I wrote the following function:

```
// Hex or Dec representation of number to int
int stringToInt(char* string) {
    int result = 0;

    if (string[0] == '0' && string[1] == 'x')
        result = strtol(string + 2, NULL, 16); // Hexa decimal number given as an input .word 0x100 0x121423
    else
        result = atoi(string); // decimal number given - .word 256 1

    printf("String = %s, result = %d\n", string, result);
    return result;

}
```

This function gets the argument `string`, and returns the integer it represents.

As a test I inserted into the function the number `0x80dd354f` and the result I see is `2147483647` instead of the expected: `2161980751`
the print line prints: `String = 0x80dd354f, result = 2147483647`

One thing I noticed, is that these errors occur only with numbers with MSB = 1.

Example: for the input `0x06866aed` the print line is:
`String = 0x06866aed, result = 109472493` as expeced.

Any tips/ideas why does this happen? It doesn't look like I am using `strtol` wrong.

Comment: OT, but there are some improvements you can make to your code.  [`strtol()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4) already handles your `if (string[0] == '0' && string[1] == 'x')` check, and does it more robustly - your code doesn't handle `"0X..."`, for example.  And exactly how robust do you want your function to be?  Try passing it something like `"qwerty"`.  `atoi()` is not robust at all, and it can actually be somewhat dangerous to use. `atoi()` not only has zero ways to indicate any error - in fact, if it can't parse the string it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `strtol()` with `base==0` returns `8` for the input `"010"` which you may don't want.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 True. At least the code ought to be using `strtol()` with base 10 in that case, not `atoi()`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 That's fully documented.  And [you **certainly** don't want to **ever** use `atoi()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1p1) given, "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined."  The only way to safely use `atoi()` is to fully parse the input, determine its value, and see if it can be safely represented as an `int`, making the call to `atoi()` superfluous.  In other words, `atoi()` is a completely useless function - you cannot sanitize its input without doing its job for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is a 32 bit type on your platform, therefore `0x80dd354f` is a negative number and you should use `unsigned int` instead of `int` and `strtoul` instead of `strtol`.

```
unsigned int stringToInt(char* string) {
  unsigned int result = 0;

  if (string[0] == '0' && string[1] == 'x')
    result = strtoul(string + 2, NULL, 16);
  else
    result = atoi(string); // decimal number given - .word 256 1

  printf("String = %s, result = %u\n", string, result);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If MSB is 1, the result doesn't fit into `long` (on your system `long` has 1 sign bit and 31 value bits). So `strtol` clamps it to closest value (`LONG_MAX`).

Of course, if it doesn't fit into `long`, it won't fit into `int` too. You should decide what you want to do in this case — silently clamp? Report an error? Do some sort of modulo-casting? If you don't care, leave the code as it is and call it "not a bug".